# Map data using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data like this:

```
const data = {
   "result":[
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:00.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":2
      },
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:01.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":2
      },
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:58.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":3
      },
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:59.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":2
      },
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:26:00.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":2
      },
      {
         "intersectionId":77,
         "deviceNumber":300,
         "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:26:01.000+0000",
         "outstationId":null,
         "occupancy":0,
         "gap":0,
         "journeyTime":null,
         "speed":0,
         "vehicleLength":0,
         "vehicleType":2
      }
   ]
};
```

I want to sort data by date, vehicleType and _sum this value. So I got from lodash

```
const groupedItems = _(data.result)
  .groupBy(item => new Date(new Date(item.timestamp).setSeconds(0,0)).toISOString())
  .mapValues((array, sort) => _.groupBy(array, item => item.vehicleType))
  .value();
```

and I got:

```
{
   "2020-10-23T07:25:00.000Z":{
      "2":[
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:00.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":2
         },
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:01.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":2
         },
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:59.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":2
         }
      ],
      "3":[
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:25:58.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":3
         }
      ]
   },
   "2020-10-23T07:26:00.000Z":{
      "2":[
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:26:00.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":2
         },
         {
            "intersectionId":77,
            "deviceNumber":300,
            "timestamp":"2020-10-23T07:26:01.000+0000",
            "outstationId":null,
            "occupancy":0,
            "gap":0,
            "journeyTime":null,
            "speed":0,
            "vehicleLength":0,
            "vehicleType":2
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

this is fine, but I want to get sum of variable (speed, vehicleLength, occupancy) for each vehicleType like this:

```
{
   "2020-10-23T07:25:00.000Z":{
      "2": { avgSpeed: 0, avgVehicleLength: 0, avgGap: 0, avgOccupancy: 0, numVehicles: 3},
      "3": { avgSpeed: 0, avgVehicleLength: 0, avgGap: 0, avgOccupancy: 0, numVehicles: 1}
   },
   "2020-10-23T07:26:00.000Z":{
      "2": { avgSpeed: 0, avgVehicleLength: 0, avgGap: 0, avgOccupancy: 0, numVehicles: 1},
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to increase the chances that your question is closed as spam, putting the pointless string of `....` at the end of your question is a sure fire way to do that.  If you are not taking your question seriously, why should we?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is REDUCE multiple values into a single one.

Thankfully for us, this use case is quite common, which means JavaScript already has a [native array method](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce) to perform such operations (and lodash has a collection of them depending on what you're trying to achieve).

From your problem statement, we need to sum up specific properties of an objects list, such as:

```
const totalSpeed = _.sumBy(items, 'speed')
```

which will "pick" the `speed` property of each item and add them up.

Now that we have a solution for our base case, we can reduce the list of items into an object containing our summed up properties:

```js
const groupedItems = _(data.result)
  .groupBy(item => new Date(new Date(item.timestamp).setSeconds(0,0)).toISOString())
  .mapValues(array => _(array)
    .groupBy(item => item.vehicleType)
    .mapValues(items => ({
      avgSpeed: _.sumBy(items, 'speed'),
      avgGap: _.sumBy(items, 'gap'),
      avgOccupancy: _.sumBy(items, 'occupancy'),
      avgVehicleLength: _.sumBy(items, 'vehicleLength'),
      numVehicles: _.size(items)
    }))
    .value()
  )
  .value();
```